# VHDL-2008 external names: reference verilog net?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, questasim

Is it possible to use VHDL-2008 hierarchical references / external names to reference Verilog nets? Questa Sim (10.6c) stops the simulation with this error message:

**vsim-8509:  The object class "SIGNAL" of "dut_i.my_net" is different from the class "net" of the denoted object.**

Here's the VHDL code that fails:

```
alias my_alias is << signal dut_i.my_net : std_logic >>;
```

Comment: This is outside of the scope of VHDL, as it cross language compatibility is not defined in the LRM. This is a tool dependent issue. How is my_net declared in the verilog? technically, everything in verilog is a variable (maybe try this instead of signal) For cross language access, you may be limited to using signalspy.

Comment: In this case *my_net* is the output of a Verilog Module (that is left unconnected/open in the next hierarchy). Using 'variable' instead of 'signal' results in a similar error.

Comment: Then I suggest reading up on signal spy (other vendors also provide similar packages, but they are all proprietary).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Questa User Manual:

> Questa SIM supports the IEEE 1076-2008 standard “external name” syntax
>   that allows you to make hierarchical references from VHDL to VHDL.
>   Currently, these references can cross Verilog boundaries, but they
>   must begin and end in VHDL.

Thus, the answer is no.

Questa does provide a set of *Signal Spy* procedures to access your Verilog signals via string names. You must also turn on optimization visability to access these signals since the strings are not parsed until run-time.

Comment: 10.6d user manual, Chapter 10 Mixed-Language Simulation, Separate Compilers with Common Design Libraries, Using Hierarchical References.